Is it possible to automatically write an Insert after every Update or Delete in EF Core
We have a Proof table that is always automatically written in the same transaction after a table row is updated or deleted. The Proof table has all the updated / deleted columns with the old and the new value.
So whenever I update a table, a corresponding row is inserted into Proof with the original values of the row and the new values.
Is it possible to replicate something like this in EF Core, or do I have to add the insert always myself?
I tried looking in the internet and the EF Core documentation but didn't find any answers.
Thank you

Posting the same incomplete question over and over and over only annoys people. Never mind that deleting previous answered question is a huge disrespect to the people that wasted time to answer you, with examples and links to the docs. Read the previous answers. didn't find any anwsers. on the contrary, there are a lot, all pointed out by answers until now

To repeat what the docs already know and the answers already said: You can use triggers, you can use temporal tables, you can use SaveChanges interceptors  and what you ask, auditing, is the example used in the docs

You might want to research: Audit Log,  (see also: Best way to implement an audit trail in SQL Server?)

@PanagiotisKanavos I literally didn`t do anything after I posted the question. It was in the "staging ground" or something like that. I got feedback and comments and tried to flag some comments as an answer but there was no option.

@Luuk the OP already asked the exact same question 3 times and got detailed answers from the very first.

@PanagiotisKanavos: I did never see those, and they seems to be deleted now....

@PoulBak the OP deleted the questions, but the possible implementations are very specific, documented, and have multiple duplicates already (eg using SaveChanges interceptors).

I didnt delete anything. I wrote this question only once and it was in the staging ground for 1 day. there i got the answers that helped me but i cannot mark the question as answered. 5 Minutes ago i got an email that my question is now visible on the main page. i really dont know why you say that i deleted this question 3 times.

I suggest you to use SaveChangesInterceptor: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors#savechanges-interception

@PanagiotisKanavos This question was automatically upgraded from Staging Ground, see the question's timeline. I'm not aware of any deleted question by OP. If there is, your first comment is justified.

To repeat my comment on the SG post: "This type of question is too broad. Basically all we can say is: no, it's not a native EF feature, so yes, do it yourself. That's not very helpful for you, let alone future visitors. That said, it's always useful to tell which database brand you're using. Some databases have native support for this (like temporal tables in SQL Server). Also, you really should be able to find other questions on this issue. Try search terms like "auditing"." To bad you didn't seem to have done anything with it.

@GertArnold thank you. I wasnt aware of the term "auditing" but that is exactly what I was looking at. I already implemented it while overriding the savechanges method.

You can override the method SaveChangesAsync of your DbContext to perform additional operation.
It should be something like:
    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        await OnBeforeSaveChangesAsync();
        int result = await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
        await OnAfterSaveChangesAsync();
        return result;
    }

